# embedded Lua loading modules programmatically (C++)

Tags: c++, lua

I am embedding Lua in a C++ application.

I have some modules (for now, simple .lua scripts) that I want to load programmatically, as the engine is being started, so that when the engine starts, the module(s) is/are available to scripts without them having to include a require 'xxx' at the top of the script.

In order to do this, I need to be able to programmatically (i.e. C++ end), ask the engine to load the modules, as part of the initialisation (or shortly thereafter).

Anyone knows how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to add and edit a copy of `linit.c` to your project.

Comment: Suppose my module is in /usr/local/lua/script/mymodule.lua, how would I modify linit.c to get the functionality required?. I have looked at the source code, and it seems to be for C packages not Lua scripts - am I missing something?

Comment: @skyeagle: Sorry, I assumed a C module. For a Lua module, you can set the environment variable LUA_INIT to say @loadmymodules.lua and in that load all your Lua modules with require.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, I just use the simple approach:  My C++ code just calls Lua's require function to pre-load the Lua scripts I want preloaded!

```
// funky = require ("funky")
//
lua_getfield (L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "require"); // function
lua_pushstring (L, "funky");     // arg 0: module name
err = lua_pcall (L, 1, 1, 0);
// store funky module table in global var
lua_setfield (L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "funky");

// ... later maybe handle a non-zero value of "err"
// (I actually use a helper function instead of lua_pcall
// that throws a C++ exception in the case of an error)
```

If you've got multiple modules to load, of course, put it in a loop... :)